# List files bigger than specified size, then create md5sum or sha256sum of them

Tags: bash, terminal, md5sum

I'd like to know how to create a list with md5sums from files in the current directory - files that are over a specified size. I can do one or the other, but I don't know how to combine the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe `find` (which will list all files you are interested in) output to `md5sum`.

`xargs` is needed to avoid creating a loop.

To write it up in a command:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -size +30M -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum`

- `.` says "start listing items from current directory"
- `-maxdepth 1` specifies to list only files in this directory (do not descend deeper)
- `-size +30M` specifies to list only files which exceed 30 megabytes of space (you can also use `k` and `G` suffixes if needed, read more about its possibilities in `man find` if needed)
- `-type f` avoids listing directories - you can't count `md5sum` for a directory
- `-print0` makes `find` separate filenames with the null byte. We use this because everything fails when you put a newline in filename.

`xargs` will take stuff from standard input (thanks to `-0` flag it will treat the null byte as record separator) and feed them as arguments to `md5sum`.

You can also make it without the pipe, but I find that syntax confusing and I prefer to pipe it to `xargs`:
`find . -maxdepth 1 -size +30M -type f -execdir md5sum {} \;`

And, as @David writes in the comments, you can put `+` after the `{}`, i.e. `find . -maxdepth 1 -size +30M -type f -execdir md5sum {} + \;`.

What does it change? `md5sum` can be called for two files in two ways: `md5sum file1; md5sum file2` or `md5sum file1 file2`. Without the `+` you get the first option, adding `+` results in executing it the second way. The most important benefit is speed, since `md5sum` executes only once. It may not be *that* beneficial for some programs, but for some cases, for example a program can then run on many cores and speed-up the work by the factor of NUM_CPUS.

About that strange syntax (from `man find`):

> -execdir command ;
>
> Execute command; `true` if `0` status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `';'` is encountered.  The  string  `'{}'` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `'\'`) or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the `-execdir` option. The  specified  command  is run once for each matched file.

Comment: Very informative I will try this ! How do I get this into a text file ? > checksums.md5 ?

Comment: Sure, just put `> checksums.md5` at the end of this "script".  Just take in mind, that if you put `checksums.md5` in your current directory it will have its (the file's `checksums.md5`) hash in it and this hash will be incorrect... It's a hard problem to create a file which has its own hash inside.

Comment: If you have GNU `find` you can use `-exec md5sum {} +` to pass all matches to a single `md5sum` command (assuming they all fit onto a single command-line).